# Get content from anyContent as Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have case class with field AnyContent. I get it from DB as

```
AnyContentAsText( //some value)
```

Than when I get it in JSON  like text

```
Json.obj("body"->content.asText)
```

it returns

```
[{"body":"AnyContentAsJson({\"ma\":\"some@email.com\"})"}]
```

When I want get it like JSON

```
Json.obj(content.asJson)
```

I get

```
[null]
```

How can I get it like JSON but not null of course?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your `case class` looks like and what the `asText` method is doing

Answer (score 1):

The only way to go from `AnyContentAsText` to `JSON` would be to simply do `Json.parse(content.asText)`.

However, it's odd that you're getting a value from your DB as `AnyContentAsText`.  `AnyContentAsText` and all other subclasses of `AnyContent` are really intended for the request lifecycle.  When you consume a request in a controller method, the first thing you should be doing is parsing your `AnyContent` into the expected underlying value (text, json, etc.) and then do any business logic/persistence with those underlying values.

Answer (score 1):

If you're receiving `AnyContentAsText` on the backend, check the request headers that the client sends.
I had forgotten the `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header on my POST with JSON content. After adding the header, I received `AnyContentAsJson` on the backend side, as expected.